# Find an outgoing email on Fedora release 16 (Verne)

Tags: email, directory, fedora

A friend has just sent an important email with a big attachment through a server I rent, and the message failed to be delivered because it was too big for the recipient's email server. Then her computer crashed and will not reboot, so she is unable to access her original message. My challenge is to locate a copy of the message on the server, and download it to my own computer, so that I can deliver it for her.

I am no expert on using the command line to communicate with a remote server. I do know how to SSH in, and I have found the following command which will allow me to locate a file containing a know pattern of text.

```
find /directory -type f -exec grep -i pattern '{}' \; -print
```

My question is: which directory should I `cd` to, in order to start the find command in the right place for an outgoing email message?

My guess is...

```
find /etc/mail -type f -exec grep -i "recipient@server.com"  '{}' \; -print
```

... but that returns immediately with no results.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of possibilities here depending on how your server is setup.  I don't think there's any guarantee the mail message is on the server.  What's the command output from `mailq` on your server?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. mailq gives me a list of 2 messages that were refused by the account of a different account holder last November. That looks like a dead end.